# "uninitialized constant Api::V1::ReservationOptionsController::ReservationOptions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api-design

I'm trying to create an API, but I get the error

```
"type": "NameError",
"message": "uninitialized constant Api::V1::ReservationOptionsController::ReservationOptions",
```

I cannot seem to find the issue here.

**Code**

routes

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :reservation_options, only: [:show, :create]
    end
end
```

controllers/api/v1/reservation_options_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ReservationOptionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, only: [:create]

  def show
    @reservation_option = ReservationOption.find(params[:id])
    @reservation = @reservation_option.reservation
    authorize @reservation_option
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @reservation_option = ReservationOptions.new(reservation_option_params)
    authorize @reservation_option
    if @reservation_option.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render_error
    end
  end

  private
  def reservation_option_params
    params.require(:reservation_option).permit(:option_id, :option_quantity, :reservation_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the action create

```rb
def create
    @user = current_user
    # change this line
    # @reservation_option = ReservationOptions.new(reservation_option_params)
    @reservation_option = ReservationOption.new(reservation_option_params)
    authorize @reservation_option
    if @reservation_option.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render_error
    end
  end
```

Comment: Wow that I didn't spot this one. Thanks Rosel!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ReservationOptions` hasn't been defined anywhere, and you're using it in `controllers/api/v1/reservation_options_controller.rb`.

Make sure you've spelled it right, or that you have the appropriate model in `app/models/reservation_option.rb`. My guess is that it should be `ReservationOption`, since Rails model class names are typically singular.

Comment: I actually see you're using `ReservationOption` up above, and that's not causing an exception, so I'm pretty sure that you need to change `ReservationOptions`